# Make Library Override with collection from current file

Tags: linked-data, collections, proxies

Is it possible to do a "Make Library Override" in order to edit an object linked to another Collection **which is in the current file**? I can do that if the collection is from another file, but this is greyed out if I duplicate collection from the current file.

Comment: No, I don't think that is supported at the moment, as far as I know